# overlay a widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm writing an application with flutter. My problems are that I have to overlay a container with a card like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2wMX.png)

I don't know how to overlay the widget with the text food.

update:

I tried with the code below but without the results that I want.

```
class _ProductsScreenState extends State<ProductsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextNameApp(),
                ContainerCard(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100.0,
                            width: 250.0,
                            child: Card(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45.0),
                              ),
                              elevation: 4.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Container card is a widget that I have create. Have the same function of a container.

[this is how the widget is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18zIN.jpg)

Comment: You can use Stack widget for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Stack` Widget, more information [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html).